# Use global to get a variable from parent function (function in function)

Tags: php

I have function in function in PHP:

```
function myfunction() {
    $content = "somecontent";
    function secondfunction() {
       global $content;
       echo $content;
    }
    secondfunction();
}
```

`global` doesn't work. Why?

Searched a lot but didn't find a solution.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What does "global doesn't work" mean in detail? Where is `global $content` defined in your code, is this piece included? What do you expect from `global`, and where does it behave different?

Comment: You realise that they're not really "nested" functions. They're both simply independent functions in the global scope.... the only difference from defining them both separately is that secondfunction() will only be defined when myfunction() is actually called

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access GLOBAL variable in php, you must first define it top level to access it on any level.
Change your code and define global in myfunction() as :

```
function myfunction() {
    global $content;
    $content = "somecontent";
    function secondfunction() {
       global $content;
       echo $content;
    }
    secondfunction();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:

```
function myfunction() {
    $content = "somecontent";
    function secondfunction($content) {
       echo $content;
    }
    secondfunction($content);
}
```

Method 2:

```
function myfunction() {
    $content = "somecontent";
    $secondfunction = function() use ($content) {
       echo $content;
    };
    $secondfunction();
}
```

You should also check Nouman Arshad's answer.